# How Can I Create and Configure Icon Themes in Gnome?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, icons, customization, design

I know the basics for designing icons but I have no idea how to configure and compile them into a file so that I can create a gnome icon theme out of them. Can anyone help? It would be much appreciated :) Or maybe even link me to a tutorial that explains the basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*By the way, you may be interested in [GNOME Look](http://gnome-look.org/), where usually they just give an archive full of icons and go 'try and install this'*    ;-)

The existing files for the icons themes are located in `/usr/share/icons`.

One of the easier ways of doing this would be to repackage a `.deb` file. So if you were to download a base one, like the one for the [gnome-icon theme](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/gnome_3/raring/main/base/gnome-icon-theme), you could then modify it as detailed [here](http://plug-and-pray.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/manually-modifying-deb-package.html).

You first need to extract the deb file in terminal, make & change to the directory you want to extract it to:

```
mkdir icondev
cd icondev
```

Then extract the deb file:

```
ar x /PATH/TO/PACKAGE.deb
```

This will extract the following files:

```
debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz
```

And make your modifactions. Make sure you change the package name *(in `control.tar.gz`, in `control`)*, and where it will install to *(in `data.tar.gz`, anything inside that)*, or it will conflict with already installed or future installs of software.

The icon theme will work as long as it inside the `/usr/share/icons` folder, and in the same format as other icon themes. The name of the theme is the name of its folder within `/usr/share/icons`, and what is in the `icon.theme` file.

You can then repackage it with this - use this command EXACTLY:

```
ar r NEW-PACKAGE.deb debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz
```

Then you can cross you fingers and install it with *(this should detail any conflicts)*:

```
sudo dpkg -i /PATH/TO/NEW-PACKAGE.deb
```

You should be able to remove it with:

```
sudo apt-get remove NEW-PACKAGE-NAME
```

Comment: So, do you know what needs to be done as far as configuration so that Gnome recognizes the icon and knows what program to attach it to? In Android development there is a line of code that says that "this is the icon & this is the program it needs to be with". Is there anything to that effect?

Comment: Open terminal with `gksudo nautilus /usr/share/icons`. Copy  the `gnome` file, and paste it. You will end up with `gnome (copy)`. Then open [`unity-tweak-tool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/), and go to icons settings. There will be a `gnome (copy)` icon theme. The name of the theme is the name of its folder within `/usr/share/icons`. It is as simple a that.

Comment: So can I theoretically take an existing icon theme and just change the icons with another icon and have them change in the theme?

Comment: @Ampersand - yes, that is the simple way to do it, but you asked to package it, so I gave you an answer for that. Sorry, I should of been clearer. As vaguely said in my answer, it is easier to modify an existing theme because of that.

Comment: No, its fine :) Thank you very much, I will let you know if I run into any problems.

Comment: @Ampersand - I don't mind - I had a go at this ages ago, but have not had time since ;-)

Comment: So inside of the theme folder there is a index.theme file, that serves as a directory, [this](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) explains the format of that, I think that was my main problem. I hope that this may help anyone else that has an issue, thank you much @wilf